# Issue with assigning static IP to docker container using Terraform

Tags: docker, terraform

Now I am trying to learn Terraform and started using it with docker container. I wanted to create a lamp stack. So the requirement is as below

- MySQL - Separate container

  - Port - 3306 needs to forward to host 8080
- PHP/Apache – Separate container

  - Port – 80 needs to forward to host 8080
- Nginx as Proxy - Separate container

  - Port – 80 need to forward to host 80

Below is my code for this requirement:

```
vi main.tf

module "db_server_vm" {
  source    = "./module"
  server_name  = "db-server"
  servers      = "1"
}

module "app_server_vm" {
  source    = "./module"
  server_name  = "app-server"
  servers      = "1"
}

module "proxy_server_vm" {
   source    = "./module"
   server_name  = "proxy-server"
   servers      = "1"
}
```

The module file is as below:

```
vi module/docker_container.tf

variable "container_image" {
   type = "string"
   default = "containers.dev.int/redhat:6.7_latest"
}

resource "docker_container" "container" {
    image = "${var.container_image}"
    name = "${var.server_name}-${count.index}"
    hostname = "${var.server_name}"
    domainname = "example.int"
    count = "${var.servers}"
    must_run = true
    restart = "always" 
    privileged = true
    env = ["env=test", "role=test"]

    command = ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D", "-o", "UseDNS=no", "-o", "PasswordAuthentication=yes", "-o", "UsePrivilegeSeparation=no", "-o", "UsePAM=no", "-o", "PidFile=/tmp/sshd.pid"]
    }
```

Using the above I am able to create the container but now I am confused how to put a logic to forward the relevant ports to host vm. Again how to assign static IP to the containers? Because I require the IP's to configure the db with app and Proxy with app

Comment: I can't help with the terraform part but this is easily accomlished with a docker compose file. Only the nginx container needs to be accessible outside the host so you use a port forwarding `-p 80:80`. All 3 containers can then run on an internal bridge network. You don't need to know the container's ip addresses. Docker has dns resolution so you can refer to a container by name.

Comment: Thanks @Alkaline for the quick response. My requirement is to orchestrate containers using Terraform only. Even port forwarding is possible using Terraform. But I am confused how to do it while consuming the resources as module.